# Reflections not reflecting properly

Tags: java, colors, raytracing, depth

I am writing a ray tracer.I am currently working on reflections.But the seem not to be reflecting correctly.I keep on getting StackOverflowError.I increased the memory and it runs now but the reflections are not like I thought the would be this.

[image: What I thought]
<sub>(source: [ageofarmour.com](http://www.ageofarmour.com/3d/tutorials/AoA_metalized_glass_shader_help_files/raytrace_depth.jpg))</sub>

I thought it would Reflect the reflections!But it just ends up like this.

Note:This is after moved the normal off the object and changed the color calculations!Check the Cal_Reflection for new color calculation!

[image: My Sad Reflections]

Here is my code for my tracer!

```
public class Tracer {

public boolean Tracing;
public Camera Cam;
public int Width, Height;
public BufferedImage Image;
public Color BackGroundColor;
public int StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY, RowCount, ColCount;
public double AmbientLight;
public double DiffuseLight;
public int MaxReflectionCount;
public ArrayList<GeometricObject> GeoObjects;
public ArrayList<LightObject> LightObjects;

public Tracer(Camera cam, int width, int height, BufferedImage image, Color backGroundColor, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int rowCount, int colCount, double ambientLight, double diffuseLight, int maxReflectionCount, ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoObjects, ArrayList<LightObject> lightObjects) {
    super();
    Cam = cam;
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
    Image = image;
    BackGroundColor = backGroundColor;
    StartX = startX;
    StartY = startY;
    EndX = endX;
    EndY = endY;
    RowCount = rowCount;
    ColCount = colCount;
    AmbientLight = ambientLight;
    DiffuseLight = diffuseLight;
    MaxReflectionCount = maxReflectionCount;
    GeoObjects = geoObjects;
    LightObjects = lightObjects;
}

public void TracePixelFast(int x, int y) {
    Color color = new Color(BackGroundColor.r, BackGroundColor.g, BackGroundColor.b);
    for (int o = 0; o < GeoObjects.size(); o++) {
        GeometricObject GO = GeoObjects.get(o);
        Ray r = new Ray(Cam.GetRayPos(Width, Height, x, y, 1, 1, RowCount, ColCount), Cam.GetRayDir(Width, Height, x, y, 1, 1, RowCount, ColCount));
        double hit = GO.hit(r);
        if (hit != 0.0) {
            color = Cal_Pixel(x, y);
            Image.setRGB(x, y, color.toInt());
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void TracePixelSmooth(int x, int y) {
    Image.setRGB(x, y, Cal_Pixel(x, y).toInt());
}

public Color Cal_Pixel(int x, int y) {
    Color color = new Color(BackGroundColor);
    Color colorh = new Color(BackGroundColor);
    Color bgc = new Color(BackGroundColor);
    int HIT = 0;
    int MISS = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < RowCount; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < ColCount; col++) {
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Ray r = new Ray(Cam.GetRayPos(Width, Height, x, y, row, col, RowCount, ColCount), Cam.GetRayDir(Width, Height, x, y, row, col, RowCount, ColCount));
            for (int o = 0; o < GeoObjects.size(); o++) {
                GeometricObject GO = GeoObjects.get(o);
                double hit = GO.hit(r);
                if (hit != 0.0 && hit < min) {
                    min = hit;
                    colorh = ShadePixel(0, GO, r, hit);
                    HIT++;
                } else {
                    double min2 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (int o2 = 0; o2 < GeoObjects.size(); o2++) {
                        if (o != o2) {
                            GeometricObject GO2 = GeoObjects.get(o2);
                            double hit2 = GO2.hit(r);
                            if (hit2 != 0.0 && hit2 < min2) {
                                min2 = hit2;
                                bgc = ShadePixel(0, GO2, r, hit2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    MISS++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int h = 0; h < HIT; h++) {
        color.Add(colorh);
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < MISS; m++) {
        color.Add(bgc);
    }
    color.Divide(RowCount * ColCount);
    return color;
}

public Color ShadePixel(int ReflectionDepthCount, GeometricObject GO, Ray ray, double t) {
    Normal normal = GO.Cal_Normal(ray, t);
    if (GO.Reflectivity > 0) {
        Color GoColor = new Color(Cal_Reflection(GO, ReflectionDepthCount, ray, normal));
        Color finalcolor = new Color(Cal_Light(GoColor, normal));
        return finalcolor;
    } else {
        ;
        Color finalcolor = new Color(Cal_Light(GO.Color, normal));
        return finalcolor;
    }
}

public Color Cal_Light(Color color, Normal normal) {
    ArrayList<Color> PixelShade = new ArrayList<Color>();
    Color Final = new Color();
    for (int l = 0; l < LightObjects.size(); l++) {
        LightObject light = LightObjects.get(l);
        Vector3D r_Dir = light.Pos.Sub(normal.Origin);
        r_Dir.normalize();
        Ray raytolight = new Ray(normal.Origin, r_Dir);
        int WAS_HIT = 0;
        for (int o = 0; o < GeoObjects.size(); o++) {
            GeometricObject NGO = GeoObjects.get(o);
            double hit = NGO.hit(raytolight);
            if (hit != 0.0) {
                WAS_HIT = 1;
            }
        }
        PixelShade.add(light.ShadePixel(WAS_HIT, normal, r_Dir, color, AmbientLight, DiffuseLight));
    }
    for (int s = 0; s < PixelShade.size(); s++) {
        Final.Add(PixelShade.get(s));
    }
    Final.Divide(PixelShade.size());
    return Final;
}

public Color Cal_Reflection(GeometricObject OriginalObject, int ReflectionDepthCount, Ray InRay, Normal normal) {
    if (ReflectionDepthCount <= MaxReflectionCount) {
        GeometricObject LastGO = null;
        Ray LastRay = null;
        double LastT = 0.0;
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Vector3D Origin = normal.Origin.Add(normal.Direction.Mul(1E-100));
        Vector3D Direction = normal.Direction;
        Direction.normalize();
        Ray r = new Ray(Origin, Direction);
        for (int o = 0; o < GeoObjects.size(); o++) {
            GeometricObject GO = GeoObjects.get(o);
            double hit = GO.hit(r);
            if (hit != 0.0 && hit < min) {
                min = hit;
                LastGO = GO;
                LastRay = r;
                LastT = hit;
            }
        }
        if (LastGO != null) {
            System.out.println(ReflectionDepthCount);
            Color Reflected = new Color(ShadePixel(ReflectionDepthCount++, LastGO, LastRay, LastT));
            Color HitColor = new Color(LastGO.Color);
            Color FinalColor = new Color(OriginalObject.Color);
            Reflected.Mul(OriginalObject.Reflectivity);
            HitColor.Mul(OriginalObject.Reflectivity);
            FinalColor.Add(HitColor);
            FinalColor.Add(Reflected);
            FinalColor.Divide(2);
            return FinalColor;
        }
    } else {
        return BackGroundColor;
    }
    return OriginalObject.Color;
}

public void TraceArea(boolean SmoothTracing) {
    Tracing = true;
    if (SmoothTracing) {
        for (int x = StartX; x < EndX; x++) {
            for (int y = StartY; y < EndY; y++) {
                TracePixelSmooth(x, y);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int x = StartX; x < EndX; x++) {
            for (int y = StartY; y < EndY; y++) {
                TracePixelFast(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Here is my code for my sphere!

```
public class Sphere extends GeometricObject{

public Vector3D Center;
public double Radius;

public Sphere(Vector3D Center,Color Color,double Radius,double Reflectivity){
    this.Center = Center;
    this.Radius = Radius;
    this.Color = Color;
    this.Reflectivity = Reflectivity;
}

public double hit(Ray ray) {
    double a = ray.Direction.Dot(ray.Direction);
    double b = 2 * ray.Origin.Sub(Center).Dot(ray.Direction);
    double c = ray.Origin.Sub(Center).Dot(ray.Origin.Sub(Center))-Radius*Radius;
    double discreminant = b*b-4*a*c;
    if(discreminant < 0.0f){
        return 0.0;
    }else{
        double t = (-b - Math.sqrt(discreminant))/(2*a);
        if(t > 10E-9){
            return t;
        }else{
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}

public Normal Cal_Normal(Ray ray,double t) {
    Vector3D NPos = new Vector3D(ray.Origin.x + ray.Direction.x*t,ray.Origin.y + ray.Direction.y*t,ray.Origin.z + ray.Direction.z*t);
    Vector3D NDir = NPos.Sub(Center).Div(Radius);
    NDir.normalize();
    return new Normal(NPos,NDir);
}}
```

And here is my launcher that controls the scene and tracer!

```
public class Launcher {
public static int Width = 600;
public static int Height = 600;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(Width, Height, 8, 8, new Color(0, 0, 0), new Camera(new Vector3D(0, 0, 30), new Vector3D(0.3, 0, -1), 1, true, Width, Height, 40), 0.1, 0.2, 2);
    // scene.AddObject(new Sphere(new Vector3D(0,0,0),new
    // Color(0,255,0),5,1));
    // scene.AddObject(new Sphere(new Vector3D(-30,0,0),new
    // Color(0,0,255),10,0.5));
    // scene.AddObject(new Sphere(new Vector3D(30,0,0),new
    // Color(255,0,0),10,0.5));
    scene.AddObject(new Sphere(new Vector3D(15, 0, 0), new Color(255, 0, 0), 15, 1));
    scene.AddObject(new Sphere(new Vector3D(-15, 0, 0), new Color(0, 0, 255), 15, 1));
    scene.AddLight(new NonColoredLight(new Vector3D(0, 0, 20), 0.1));
    long Start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BufferedImage Image = scene.Trace(false, 2);
    long End = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Milli Seconds To Render " + (End - Start));
    File ImageFile = new File("TracedImage.png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(Image, "PNG", ImageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

And here is the scene code!

```
public Scene(int width, int height, int row, int col, Color backGroundColor, Camera cam, double ambientLight, double diffuseLight, int maxReflectionCount) {
    super();
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
    Row = row;
    Col = col;
    BackGroundColor = backGroundColor;
    Cam = cam;
    AmbientLight = ambientLight;
    DiffuseLight = diffuseLight;
    MaxReflectionCount = maxReflectionCount;
    GeoObjects = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
    LightObjects = new ArrayList<LightObject>();
    if (ambientLight > 1) {
        AmbientLight = 1;
    } else if (ambientLight < 0) {
        AmbientLight = 0;
    } else {
        AmbientLight = ambientLight;
    }
    if (diffuseLight > 1) {
        DiffuseLight = 1;
    } else if (diffuseLight < 0) {
        DiffuseLight = 0;
    } else {
        DiffuseLight = ambientLight;
    }
}

public void AddObject(GeometricObject GO) {
    GeoObjects.add(GO);
}

public void AddLight(LightObject Light) {
    LightObjects.add(Light);
}

public BufferedImage Trace(boolean SmoothTracing, int ThreadCount) {
    Image = new BufferedImage(Width, Height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Tracer tracer = new Tracer(Cam, Width, Height, Image, BackGroundColor, 0, 0, Width, Height, Row, Col, AmbientLight, DiffuseLight, MaxReflectionCount, GeoObjects, LightObjects);
    tracer.TraceArea(SmoothTracing);

    return Image;
}}
```

If you need me to post any more of my code just let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Variables for first reflection!

```
AmbientLight    0.1 
BackGroundColor Color  (id=39)  
    b   0.0 
    g   0.0 
    r   0.0 
Cam Camera  (id=41) 
    Direction   Vector3D  (id=104)  
        x   0.3 
        y   0.0 
        z   -1.0    
    Distance    357.526077778263    
    FOV 40.0    
    Height  600 
    Perspective true    
    PixelSize   1.0 
    Pos Vector3D  (id=115)  
        x   0.0 
        y   0.0 
        z   30.0    
    u   Vector3D  (id=116)  
        x   -0.9578262852211514 
        y   0.0 
        z   -0.28734788556634544    
    v   Vector3D  (id=117)  
        x   0.0 
        y   1.0 
        z   0.0 
    w   Vector3D  (id=118)  
        x   0.2873478855663454  
        y   0.0 
        z   -0.9578262852211513 
    Width   600 
    ColCount    8   
   DiffuseLight 0.1 
   EndX 600 
   EndY 600 
GeoObjects  ArrayList<E>  (id=43)   
    [0] Sphere  (id=26) 
    [1] Sphere  (id=34) 
Height  600 
Image   BufferedImage  (id=50)  
    accelerationPriority    0.5 
    colorModel  DirectColorModel  (id=120)  
    imageType   1   
    osis    null    
    properties  null    
    raster  IntegerInterleavedRaster  (id=124)  
    surfaceManager  null    
LightObjects    ArrayList<E>  (id=59)   
    [0] NonColoredLight  (id=88)    
MaxReflectionCount  2   
RowCount    8   
StartX  0   
StartY  0   
Tracing true    
Width   600 
OriginalObject  Sphere  (id=26) 
Center  Vector3D  (id=60)   
Color   Color  (id=61)  
Radius  15.0    
Reflectivity    1.0 
ReflectionDepthCount    0   
InRay Ray  (id=29)  
Direction   Vector3D  (id=62)   
Origin  Vector3D  (id=63)   
normal Normal  (id=31)  
Direction   Vector3D  (id=38)   
Origin  Vector3D  (id=36)   
LastGO Sphere  (id=34)  
Center  Vector3D  (id=64)   
Color   Color  (id=65)  
Radius  15.0    
Reflectivity    1.0 
LastRay Ray  (id=35)    
Direction   Vector3D  (id=38)   
Origin  Vector3D  (id=36)   
LastT 4.2468950498166125    
min 4.2468950498166125  
Origin Vector3D  (id=36)    
x   0.5809721247344103  
y   -0.023188722729640822   
z   0.8135930637731328  
Direction     Vector3D  (id=38) 
x   -0.32494278056317   
y   -0.02694400302823308    
z   0.9453497818589108  
r     Ray  (id=35)  
Direction   Vector3D  (id=38)   
Origin  Vector3D  (id=36)
```

[Project Zip File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzq1jnxsi02k4ol/RayTracer.rar?dl=0%22Project%20zip%22)

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger?

Comment: Have you a log of your code running ?

Comment: No not yet.Let me try that.

Comment: I will have to put in the question.It is too long.

Comment: Your image is not showing up again.

Answer (score 2):

You are reflecting your ray **exactly** on the surface of the object. When checking intersections with the reflected ray, you hit on the same object again. You assume that checking if the distance is equal to 0.0 is enough to avoid this, but FP numbers are trickier than you think...

Comment: So how would i fix that.I think i could do normal.origin + (normal.direction*realysmallnumber) = newRayOrgin;

Comment: This should put the ray off the objects surface!

Comment: Either that, or rather than comparing intersection distance along the reflected ray with 0.0 (which does not work with FP numbers), test if it is smaller than some very small value.